# How can I determine my application version inside appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application running in appengine. Is there an API to programmatically determine my application version? Specifically, I want to query the version: attribute in the app.yaml file.

Hans Then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention `app.yaml`, it seems fair to assume you're using Python. The details of the current version are available as an environment variable:

```
os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']
```

See [the runtime environment documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Environment).

Comment: app.yaml is also used by the Go runtime, where you would call appengine.VersionID (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/reference#VersionID).

Answer (score -1):

(Edit : I didn't know 'app.yaml' was PYTHON only, you can discard my anwser then, as it's for JAVA^^)

in **java** there is this way to get a version of the current application, was that what you were looking for?

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT //or
com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT

string version = GWT.getVersion();
```